# How do I get slack to remind me every fortnight from next Saturday

Tags: slack

Slack has the `/remind` command that allows you to set a reminder in a channel. I am trying to have slack remind me every **fortnight** starting from next Saturday at 8pm to jump on a call. It seems like an extension of the [help documentation](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/208423427-Setting-reminders#adding-a-new-reminder).

I tried:

`/remind @here Fortnightly planning and retro every fortnight from saturday at 8pm`

but it didn't work and the reminder states:

`I will remind space-racing “planning and retro every fortnight from saturday at 8pm” at 9AM every other Saturday (next occurrence is April 22nd).`

Any thoughts? thanks in advance

Comment: turns out it doesn't understand every fortnight - instead you can do: /remind #channel to do fortnightly planning and retro every two weeks at 8pm'

Answer (score 197):

I was trying to do this today also. Either of these options work:

- Needs to be run *the week before* you want it to start:

  ```
  /remind me to "ABC" every other Saturday 8pm
  /remind me to "ABC" Saturday 8pm every 2 weeks
  ```
- Otherwise specify the start date

  ```
  /remind me to "ABC" Jun 19th 8pm every 2 weeks
  /remind me to "ABC" next Saturday 8pm every 2 weeks
  ```

Slackbot told me:

> I will remind you to “ABC” at 8PM every other Saturday (next occurrence is June 19th).

Answer (score 7):

Only achievable when setting a reminder <7 days when the first occurrence should happen. For example if you want to set the reminder at Saturday May 9th at 8pm, the earliest you can set the reminder is Saturday May 2nd 8:01pm

Then you run a command like so:

```
/remind #my-channel @my-group-to-notify This is my reminder message at 8pm every other Saturday
```

You can skip the channel or group of course. But it's nice if you run some team ceremonies and want to set reminder to specific people to attend a meeting etc.

Hint: you always set the time as per your current timezone, if other people are in different time zone the reminder will be at their time, so you don't need to worry that 8pm might be for them later/earlier. You all will see reminder in the same moment.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the starting date by the keyword `starting` at the end.

```
/remind #my-channel @my-group-to-notify This is my reminder message at 8pm every other Saturday starting April 29nd
```

Answer (score 0):

But you need to set this. they week before you want to get notified. 
For e.g Today is 7th September 2018 ( Friday) and you want to get notified on 21st September 2018 ( Friday ) i.e second Friday after today ( Friday ). 
you need to use this command on next Friday. ie. on 14th September 2018 , use this command and slack will start reminding you after every other( second ) friday.

Example Command on SlackBot :

/remind me to "Send : Time Sheet" every other Friday 11am

Comment: I use this command to set reminder for my *Time Sheet* every two weeks on Friday. and it works very well for me. Regards , Deepak